# How do i selected the value from drop down if value match with the function?

Tags: php, dropdown, html-select

How do I select the value from the drop-down if the value matches the function generated values? Unable to select the value for example if `$match value is 08:00` condition should select the value from the drop-down list?

**PHP Function**

```
function create_time_range($start, $end, $interval = '15 mins', $format = '12') {
$startTime = strtotime($start);
$endTime   = strtotime($end);
$returnTimeFormat = ($format == '12')?'H:i':'H:i';

$current   = time();
$addTime   = strtotime('+'.$interval, $current);
$diff      = $addTime - $current;

$times = array();
while ($startTime < $endTime) {
    $times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $startTime);
    $startTime += $diff;
}
$times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $startTime);
return $times;
}

$times= create_time_range('00:00', '23:45', '15 mins');

$match = '08:00';
```

**Html**

```
<select name="time_picker">
<option value="">Select Time</option>
<?php foreach($times as $key=>$val){ ?>

    <?php
    if (in_array($match, $times))
    {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    ?>

  <option <?php echo $selected ?> value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your html part to following

```
<select name="time_picker">
<option value="">Select Time</option>
<?php foreach($times as $key=>$val){ 
  $selected = $match===$val ? 'selected' : '';
?>
  <option <?php echo $selected ?> value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful please accept it or upvote it :-)

Comment: sorry unable to mark it because i have less reputation it's required max 15 reputation